# Remove parent path in array

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, nsurl

I am stuck in an issue, where I need to remove all the items from the array that are in the hierarchy (if any folder lies under it).

An example will help to understand it easily.

The following is the array:

```
/Users/anoopvaidya/Doc/HierarchyDefect/A,
/Users/anoopvaidya/Doc/HierarchyDefect/A 2,
/Users/anoopvaidya/Doc/HierarchyDefect/A 2/B,
/Users/anoopvaidya/Doc/HierarchyDefect/A 2/B/BB01234567890123,
/Users/anoopvaidya/Doc/HierarchyDefect/A/B,
/Users/anoopvaidya/Doc/HierarchyDefect/A/B/BB012345678901234
```

From here I need to remove all the items leaving these two since others are parent path of either or this.

/Users/anoopvaidya/Doc/HierarchyDefect/A 2/B/BB01234567890123
and
    /Users/anoopvaidya/Doc/HierarchyDefect/A/B/BB012345678901234

What could be the best way to do this? Or I need to loop through and do some string comparison and remove the items from the array?

Your help will is highly required and appreciated.

Comment: You have to loop. And a Cocoa solution would loop, too. Maybe `-hasPrefix:` (`NSString`)  is helpful.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: In the above case it will come YES for all the items. So will give me incorrect result

Comment: No, when you check the first one against the last one or the 5th vs. the 4th. But I assumed that you can have completely different entries in that array, i. e. */Users/aminnegm/…*. Of course you have to eliminate false positives with a test of equality. (I wrote *maybe helpful* not *complete solution*)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this:

```
//sort the files
NSArray *sortedFiles = [pathArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
//then look if parent is there, if yes remove the parent
NSMutableArray *mArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:sortedFiles];
for (NSString *str in sortedFiles) {
    NSMutableArray *broken = [[str componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] mutableCopy];
    [broken removeLastObject];
    NSString *parent = [broken componentsJoinedByString:@"/"];
    if ([mArray containsObject:parent]) {
        [mArray removeObject:parent];
    }

}
```

Comment: This can be simplified considerably by using stringByDeletingLastPathComponent